# Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have the standard version of the Eclipse IDE.  That has a number of important projects on it.  However, I need to use "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".  There are a few related questions that I have:

1. Is there a way to upgrade my Eclipse IDE to "Java EE Developers" without actually have to reinstall the entire Eclipse IDE (I tried simply searching Eclipse marketplace and there was nothing there as far as upgrades to Java EE Developers is concerned)
2. If an upgrade is made (assuming the answer to #1 is "yes") to "Java EE Developers" will the current applications on the Eclipse IDE be deleted and will they still work on the "Java EE Developers".

As I have no experience with "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" it makes sense to ask these questions to people who have had experience with it.

Comment: Please edit to set a relevant title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to download `Eclipse for Java EE Developpers` and create a new workspace for `Java EE applications`. You will still be able to work on your `Java SE` projects in another workspace, with the same `Eclipse` version.

Comment: Sure, the new Eclipse may simply rewrite the project and configuration files (not the sources nore the data). However, it won't exactly replace the old Eclipse, the old version will still be installed

Comment: Okay, Thanks.  I'll try that.  I appreciate you taking the time to give me this advice.

Comment: As a follow-up, the installation of the Java EE version created a separate instance of Eclipse that shared a common set of files with the Standard Edition, so everything worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a begginer at eclipse but i would download eclipse for java ee developers and try run /try open your projects from "EE" itself even copy and paste a project on to your desktop and try "EE" with that project.you should be okay answering the question that your ide isn't going to overwritten